# What does upgrading an Uplink do?

Tags: grav

In Grav, an [Uplink](http://grav.gamepedia.com/Uplink) allows one to set a spawn point for the current world.
[image: Uplink building]

Like other buildings, an Uplink can be upgraded, but it's not clear what happens when an Uplink is upgraded or how it affects respawning.  The only things I can guess it might do is either reduce the cost of respawning or reduce the cost of binding to the Uplink, but I haven't confirmed either yet.

What effect does upgrading an Uplink have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price of binding to an uplink goes down per level and the building becomes stronger.

[One of the devs said](http://steamcommunity.com/app/332500/discussions/0/618459405710306067/#c618459405712927297) "we may add other benefits to upgrading them soon though..".